# A matrix polynomial convergent to a matrices’ transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-analysis

> Is it true that for all $A \in \mbox{GL}(n)$ there exists $c_i$ such that the following holds? $$\sum^\infty_{i=0} c_i A^i = A^T$$

---

For symmetric matrices, it is simple. I suspect some rotation matrix can not be expressed like that but I haven’t found any. Any help?

Comment: Consider triangular matrices.

Comment: I suppose your $A$ is real. If $A^T$ is a power series in $A$, it must commute with $A$ and hence $A$ is a normal matrix. The converse is also true, but the proof is less obvious.